# Вывод сообщений в TextArea каждый раз когда вызывается метод

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть html форма:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>

<form th:method="post" action="/" th:object="${dates}">
    <textarea class="logs" name="logs" id="logs"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
    const logsTextArea = document.querySelector('#logs');
    let lastUpdatedMessage = '';

    function getLogsAndUpdateTextArea() {
        fetch('/logs')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                if (data !== lastUpdatedMessage) {
                    logsTextArea.value += data;
                    logsTextArea.scrollTop = logsTextArea.scrollHeight;
                    lastUpdatedMessage = data;
                }
            });
    }

    setInterval(getLogsAndUpdateTextArea, 1);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

На форме `textarea`, куда выводятся сообщения из класса `CreateFile.getMessage();`

Есть REST-контроллер, который выводит сообщения в `textarea`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/logs")
public class LogsController implements MessageUpdateListener {

    private final CreateFile createFile;
    private String lastMessageUpdate = "";
    private String currentMessageUpdate = "";

    @Autowired
    public LogsController(CreateFile createFile) {
        this.createFile= createFile;
        this.createFile.addMessageUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLogs() {
        String message = createFile.getMessage();
        if (!message.equals(lastMessageUpdate)) {
            currentMessageUpdate = message;
            lastMessageUpdate = message;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(currentMessageUpdate + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageUpdate(String message) {
        currentMessageUpdate = message;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface MessageUpdateListener {
    void onMessageUpdate(String message);
}
```

Класс CreateFile:

```
@Service
public class CreateFile {

    private String message = "";
    private final List<MessageUpdateListener> messageUpdateListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    public CreateFile() {}

    public void addMessageUpdateListener(MessageUpdateListener listener) {
        messageUpdateListeners.add(listener);
        listener.onMessageUpdate(message);
    }

    public void removeMessageUpdateListener(MessageUpdateListener listener) {
        messageUpdateListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        if (!this.message.equals(message)) {
            this.message = message;
            notifyMessageUpdateListener(message);
        }
    }

    private void notifyMessageUpdateListener(String message) {
        for (MessageUpdateListener listener : messageUpdateListeners) {
            listener.onMessageUpdate(message);
        }
    }

    public List<Usl> readDBF(String[] check_otd) {
        ***
        setMessage("Чтение данных ");
        ***
    }

    public List<Usl> selectCorrectUsl(String[] checks) {
        List<Usl> list = readDBF(checks);
        
        setMessage("Проверка корректности услуг. Начало");

        return list;
    }

}
```

Метод `setMessage` вызывается во многих местах класс, но для простоты оставила в двух местах. Все работает в принципе, только есть один момент. Если текст сообщения не изменяется, то в textarea не выводится информация. Как сделать чтобы при каждом вызове setMessage в textarea сразу же выводилась информация?

Answer (score 0):

Со стороны бекенда это не сделать, бэкэнд это сервер отвечающий на запросы, он не инициирует сам соединение. Вам надо это делать со стороны фронтенда, во многих местах вызывается у вас `setMessage` - надо создать новый метод фронтенда который вызывает `setMessage` а после этого обновляет нужные компоненты html. И вот этот метод фронтенда вызывать везде где вы устанавливаете сообщение.

Comment: Не могли бы привести небольшой пример для моего случая? С JS не знакома, только пытаюсь в этой вникнуть.

Comment: К сожалению без информации о вашем фронтенде никак,  непонятно как обновлять компоненты. Вам нужен другой вопрос с описанием фронтенда и вопросом «как обновить в нем компоненты?»

Comment: Во фронте только то что я выше скинула. Простая html страница с формой.

Comment: Вы пишите что Метод setMessage вызывается во многих местах класс,в вашем сейчас представленном нет ни одного вызова

Comment: Я для примера оставила вызова в двух местах readDBF и selectCorrectUsl в этих местах

Comment: Метод setMessage это метод класса CreateFile.. Каждый раз когда этот метод вызывается метод getMessage возвращает результат, помещенный туда. Я хочу понять как правильно выводить в textarea результат метода getMessage, каждый раз когда вызовом setMessage помещается туда значение. Если бы это было например JavaFX приложение там бы я просто сделала textArea.appendText(текст). Его бы вызывала каждый раз когда нужно, а в spring boot так вроде нельзя или я не знаю как сделать такое

Comment: Это не фронтэнд, это бэкэнд. Бэкэнд сам без запроса ничего не сообщит фронту. у вас во фронтенде должно что-то вызывать бэкенд , если это взаимодействие инициируется не со стороны фронтенд, а в бэке само по себе происходит , тогда например во фронтенде по асинхронному таймеру каждую секунду спрашивать бэкенд - дай данные.

Comment: Я с фронтом не знакома особо.. но контроллер LogsController  пишет данные в методе getLogs(), а скрипт из html берет их и выводит.. Так вроде работает код выше. Его писала не я, другой пример был взят за основу контроллера LogsController   и скрипта